# Local Notification not always sending

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I set up a **Local Notification** to fire off at 7:45:01 PM every day, but it is **not firing on a daily basis at that time**.

Any idea what I'm missing here?  I've tried editing the code, but am still stuck knowing what I'm missing.

*Will post any extra code as needed, thanks!*

`AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

`ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    comp.hour = 19; // 19 = 7PM
    comp.minute = 45; // 7:45 PM
    comp.second = 01; // 7:45:01 PM

    localNotification.fireDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Local Notification in iOS8";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I set up a Local Notification to fire off at 7:45:01 PM every day

No, you didn't. You set up a local notification to fire off *once*. You didn't set any `repeatInterval` so this is not a repeating notification. It fires once and that's that.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  Will Accept answer when it lets me-